# GridView Row click event in ASP.Net i want to get id and send it to another page when click on row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = "location.href='MailsByOne.aspx?id=" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "id") + "'";
        e.Row.Attributes["style"] = "cursor:pointer";
    }
}
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    contacts connn = new contacts();
    int index = GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex;
    int ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text);
    string message = "Row Index: " + index + "\\ContactID: " + connn.ContactID;
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);
}
```

GridView Row click event in ASP.Net i want to get id and send it to another page when click on row .

Comment: Use DataKeyName Property to get Id

Comment: show your .aspx page

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] =
                this.Page.ClientScript.
               GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.grdList, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
        }
}

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        GridViewRow SelectedRow = grdList.SelectedRow;
        string id = SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
        Response.Redirect("~/Mail/ShowMail.aspx?q="+id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use Datakeynames property in gridview

```
<asp:GridView DataKeyNames="your Id you want to send">
```

and In your .cs code will be

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 string id= gvCustomReports.DataKeys[int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())].Values[0].ToString();
 Response.Redirect("MailsByOne.aspx?contactid="+id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink((Control)sender, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
    }
}  

protected void gridInterventions_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
   GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];
   int ID = Convert.ToInt32(row .Cells[0].Text);
   //Send your id here 
   //You can use session to save the id on one page and read in the target page
   Session["id"]=id; 
}
```

Good luck:)

Answer (score 0):

```
void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    // Get the currently selected row using the SelectedRow property.
    GridViewRow row = gridview1.SelectedRow;

    //now get the labels if you use Template Fields 
    Label _LabelId = row.FindControl("LabelId") as Label;


//if You use Bound Fields then
int ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text);
    Response.Redirect("~/Mail/ShowMail.aspx?q="+id);

}
```